# How to override a partial class property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have a partial class and I want to do something like the following:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UserMetaData))]
public partial class Person
{
    public override string PrivateData
    {
        get
        {
            return customDecrypt(base.PrivateData);
        }
        set
        {
            base.PrivateData = customEncrypt(value);
        }
    }
}
```

the above does not work however.

Is there a way to override the base entity framework classes its properties to allow for custom getter/setter?

Comment: trying using "public new string PrivateData" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4(v=vs.71).aspx#vclrfnew_newmodifier

Comment: Is the base class property defined as `virtual`?

Comment: Where's the BaseClass definition? Like `public partial class Person : PersonBase`?

Comment: @Akku - My guess is that there isn't a base class, it's just the other half of the partial the OP wants to override.

Comment: Mike Valstar: Please define "does not work". Also, the suggestion of mosca125 sounds reasonable :-)

Comment: The error you get, because the rest of the class is defined from the identity. is: "PrivateData" is defined twice

Comment: Also, the [line MetadataType(typeof(UserMetaData))] has no class named UserMetaData... unless such a class exists somewhere else in your project. You cannot use override in a partial class.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Partial classes have nothing to do with inheritance, and `override` is entirely about inheritance.

The `partial` keyword on a class just means that it can be declared multiple times in the same assembly.  It's exactly the same as if you copied every part of every `partial class` into the same file and removed the `partial` keyword.  Since you can't define the same property/function/etc twice in the same class, you can't define it twice in two separate parts of the same class, even with the `partial` keyword.

`override`, on the other hand, is used in *derived* classes to indicate that they're replacing the functionality of the base class they inherit from.  If it doesn't explicitly inherit, it inherits from `object`, which lets you override `ToString()` (among others).

Your best options to do what you want are either to use a custom T4 template to generate the encrypt/decrypt logic, or to set the encrypted properties to `protected` or `private` in the designer and manually add `public` versions which do the decryption.

Answer (score 2):

If you can change code generator, you can easy "emulate" it ("overriding" default values) using extrimely powerfull **partial methods**.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx

Answer (score 2):

While you can't override the Entity Framework base classes, there is a work around.  In the .edmx model (for DB first, direct in entities if code first) on the propery you want to 'override' change the Getter / Setter to private and rename the property.  Then create the partial class with the property using the public name, which will no longer conflict.

In the public partial class property you will be able to access the private renamed property if needed.